# change column values each specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am playing around a large dataset which almost 200 columns and 70000 rows. It is such a messy data so I should make more readable.

[image]

In the data columns are means:
`ATT_A(agree)`,  `ATT_SA(Strongly agree)`,  `ATT_D(disagree)` and so on

every 5 columns represent only 1 answer

my Idea is, I can use `.replace()` function and then make every 1 values column represented value (if the column name .._SA then column values should be `'SA'` instead of 1)

then I can join 5 columns in one column. It will be less messy.

IDEA_COLUMN

```
SA
A
SD
A
D
SA
```

Here my code I tried around.

```
for c in cols.columns:
    if c.upper()[:4] == 'ATT_':
        if c[-2:] == 'SA':
             c.replace('1', 'SA')
```

I tried many times so many different types but I cannot see my mistakes.
I am new on coding so I can have silly mistakes.

Comment: Can you make a small reproducible example with the image replaced with easy to copy and paste text?

Comment: I changed the picture I hope it is more clear now. I would love share csv.example but I couldn't do it sorry.

Comment: Can you show a few proportion of your data frame in text(copy and paste)? Such as `df.filter(regex = "TECHIMP").head()`. Just wondering what are those values that are not 1 in the columns. 0 or NaN?

Comment: I hope I understood true. here a TECHIMP:
`ATT_TECHIMP_A
0 NaN
1 NaN
2 NaN
3 NaN
4 1.0` `ATT_TECHIMP_D
0 1.0
1 1.0
2 NaN
3 NaN
4 NaN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
# split the columns at the second underscore to make the columns a multi-index
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit("_", n=1, expand=True)    

# transform the answer A,SA,D... to a column, group by level 0(row number) and find out the
# answer corresponding to 1 with idxmax
df.stack(level=1).groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: x.idxmax()[1])
```

[image]

---

*Another option*:

```
# split columns as above
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit("_", n=1, expand=True)    

# group columns based on the prefix along axis 1, and for each row find out the index with 
# value 1 using idxmax() function
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda g: g.apply(lambda x: x.idxmax()[1], axis = 1))
```

---

*Data Set Up*:

```
cols1 = ["ATT_TECHIMP_" + x for x in ["SA", "A", "NO", "D", "SD"]]
cols2 = ["ATT_BBB_" + x for x in ["SA", "A", "NO", "D", "SD"]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, None, None, None, None], [None, None, 1, None, None], [None, None, 1, None, None], [None, None, None, 1, None], [None, None, None, None, 1]], columns=cols1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[None, 1, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, 1], [None, None, 1, None, None], [None, None, None, 1, None], [None, None, None, None, 1]], columns=cols2)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```